# Can't restart nginx web server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server

I have a DigitalOcean droplet, after launching a laravel app into production I tried the following command:

sudo systemctl reload nginx

But I get this error:

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I ran sudo nginx -t to see if there were errors but conf and syntax is ok, after that I ran:

sudo nano /var/log/nginx/error.log

and I got this:

```
2020/01/16 14:53:53 [notice] 14195#14195: signal process started
2020/01/16 14:53:53 [error] 14195#14195: invalid PID number "" in "/run/nginx.pid"
2020/01/16 14:53:53 [emerg] 14198#14198: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/01/16 14:53:53 [emerg] 14198#14198: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/01/16 14:53:53 [emerg] 14198#14198: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/01/16 14:53:53 [emerg] 14198#14198: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/01/16 14:53:53 [emerg] 14198#14198: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/01/16 14:53:53 [emerg] 14198#14198: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/01/16 14:53:53 [emerg] 14198#14198: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/01/16 14:53:53 [emerg] 14198#14198: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/01/16 14:53:53 [emerg] 14198#14198: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/01/16 14:53:53 [emerg] 14198#14198: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/01/16 14:53:53 [emerg] 14198#14198: still could not bind()
```

Any idea why I can't restart my web server, my webs are still visible but I can't seem to restart or reload nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems as problem with `/run/nginx.pid` which is for some reason empty.

first check processes `ps -ef | grep nginx` find threre root process for nginx (in my case `7388`)

```
root@keybu:/var/www/keybu_production#  ps -ef | grep nginx
root      2314  9443  0 21:28 pts/0    00:00:00 grep nginx
root      7388     1  0  2019 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
nginx    23709  7388  0 Jan15 ?        00:00:04 nginx: worker process
```

then kill it:

```
kill -9 7388
```

- check if there is no nginx proccess running, if it is kill it also.

then restart nginx `service nginx start`

- Second solution could be write ID number of process to the `/run/nginx.pid` but haven't test it

Comment: You say yours is 7388 but you kill 25057, why is that ? also, what does the -9 mean in kill command? pardon my noobness

Comment: @gabogabans  Sry my bad, it was port `7388` for me fixed code... good eyes. `-9` is "signal" to process which ensures that the process is effectively killed. More on that here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/kill